# Azure Function & Document DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I'm curious how the scaling working on the Azure Functions with relation to outputting to Document DB.

Basically what happens when Document DB returns a 429 because I'm exceeded my allocated throughput?  I ask because when I had the lowest level of Azure Functions combined with the lowest level of Document DB and proceeded to call the function 1000 times in 20 sec I was only seeing 700-800 actual documents inserted into my document db collection.  When I scaled Document DB up to the max with the same lowest Function level again I only received 700-800 documents in my doc db collection.  However when I scaled the Function up to the max with the document db at the max I get all 1000.  When I drop doc db down to the min I only got 300ish....though it does seem like I've locked the doc db account up and that it's still retrying the insert until it can succeed.

So I'm just confused as to this is scaling and if I could get some insight so I could better tune various aspect of the function or app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does currently retry on 429, waiting the suggested amount of time as per the DocDB response. There's currently no absolute timeout so the retries will continue until they get through (I'm double-checking right now if this is the expected behavior).

In your first scenario, if you wait long enough for the throttle to be removed, do all 1000 eventually show up?

I'd like to try replicating this -- are you sticking 1000 items in a queue before enabling your function? Or calling it some other way?

The specific retry code that's running is here if you're curious:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB/DocumentDBUtility.cs#L36

Comment: I'm triggering the function via http since I don't believe service bus triggers in c# are currently functional (though that may have changed since this is changing rapidly at the moment).  So I do trigger all 1000 via the http, I'm using loader.io to do this calling a web api endpoint within my code which in turn fires the http post to trigger the function.  The loader.io test is set to run 50 requests/sec for 20 sec.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if the function eventually finish.  In my last test no more records seemed to be being written, but I was still getting 429's when I tried to interact with the doc db collection.  So I deleted the whole collection and recreated it and then saw additional records written to the collection.  So it does seem as though it was still trying, but also seemed like it was in an odd state.

Comment: Well, after a bunch of testing today I came to realize that I removed the actual sleep from this bit of code in my last change: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/commit/d39943965d45038ebddc7d4a2d729beab8a678ac#diff-6f209fbf17e36efd4d9ebc6a285cc00cL69. I'll fix this and add some tests to verify it doesn't happen again. I'll write back here when this fix is available and I'll try some more testing to make sure it works as it used to. Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: This has now been updated in production -- give it a try again. The behavior should be a bit saner. The retries now happen a max of 10 times, which means you'll start getting errors when DocDB is returning too many 429s, but that is to be expected when under load.

Comment: Just a note: it appears that in the current version of Cosmos db bindings, there are no built-in 429 retries at all.