# How to set the number of retries for Azure DocumentDB output binding in Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460452/azure-function-document-db), it seems like writing to Azure DocDB output binding in Azure Function will be retried 10 times if throttled (HTTP 429). I haven't verified this myself though.

I would like to increase this limit on the number of retries. My data comes in big chunks in a small amount of time and then with a very long period of downtime, which means that getting 429 and waiting for a bit is okay for my purpose. I must guarantee though, that no data is dropped.

One way for me to solve this is to increase the RTU limit in Document DB to make sure I don't get 429 during the time big chunks of data come in, but it's already at about 2.5 times of what I need during downtime period. Is there anyway to make the retries run infinitely until it succeeds, or less ideally, increase the number of retries to something more than 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you change the approach and instead of inserting documents right away you can make use of service bus and implement a dead letter queue, here are some links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus
- https://blog.jeroenmaes.eu/2017/01/process-service-bus-dead-letter-message-with-azure-functions/

The idea is having something like this:

1. Current function instead of saving the data in DocumentDB, it will be sending it the the service bus (you just change the output binding)
2. Another function will process every message of the service bus and if it failed (you can manage a timeout in the function and then move the message to a dead letter queue)
3. Another function that will process any message in the dead letter queue

You just need to make a small change in the first function and create two more, might sound too complicated but you'll have strong consistency in the data. In all of the above links there's an example of what I mentioned here.

Comment: Instead of moving to DLQ, you can setup the amount of retries for Service Bus queue to a high value.

Comment: @Mikhail yes, sure, but my point was to give another option :)

Comment: This sounds good to me. I have accepted your answer and will implement this instead. Thanks :D

Comment: awesome, glad it helped